# Apache 2.2.25 LocationMatch failing regex

Tags: apache, locationmatch

I am trying to upgrade Apache from 2.2.22 to 2.2.25 but I am running in to trouble with the LocationMatch Directive not using the regular expressions.  I have 2 example location match definitions below, I have the first one working, but if I try to have a regular expression in 2.2.25 it is not working, where in the old 2.2.22 it did.

The logs just shows: File does not exist: /mw01/ss/httpd/htdocs/dxxx

Is there something I am just not seeing or missed in the compile?

Sample config:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.10.42:8888>
ServerName myalias.domain.com:8888
ServerAdmin serveradmin@domain.com

<LocationMatch "/dt" >
  ProxyPass http://jda901.domain.com:8080/mtss/getHeader
  ProxyPassReverse http://jda901.domain.com:8080/mtss/getHeader
</LocationMatch>

<LocationMatch "/(dxxx|exxx)/">
  ProxyPass http://jda901.domain.com:8080/mtss/getHeader
  ProxyPassReverse http://jda901.domain.com:8080/mtss/getHeader
</LocationMatch>

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the beginning and ending characters?

Comment: I have downvoted this "answer'' because this is far from an actual answer. I believe this would be better suited as a comment on the question.